# Why does the picture not show in a loop?

Tags: python

```
from PIL import Image
Pikachu=Image.open('pikachu.png')
Charizard=Image.open('charizard.png')

pokemon_list=('PIKACHU','CHARIZARD')
picture={'PIKACHU':Pikachu,'CHARIZARD':Charizard}
Pokemon=pokemon_list[Count]

Count=0
while (Count!=3):
    picture[Pokemon]
    Count+=1
```

The picture does not show up when it is in a loop, how do I make it work?

Comment: Check my answer and correct the tag. It's not about `jupyter-notebook` but `python` or `PIL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you call it in wrong order. Notice, that you have 2 elements in list, so you cannot get more objects than [0], [1]. And you need to open files in `rb` mode.

And finally to `show` an `Image`, you have to use that funtion: `show()`.

Full code here:

```
from PIL import Image

Pikachu = open('1.jpg', 'rb')
Charizard = open('2.jpg', 'rb')

pokemon_list = ('PIKACHU', 'CHARIZARD')
picture = {'PIKACHU': Pikachu, 'CHARIZARD': Charizard}

Count = 0
while Count < 2:
    Pokemon = pokemon_list[Count]
    Image.open(picture[Pokemon]).show()
    Count += 1
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to show the picture within the jupyter notebook instead of opening it in another place, but your code does help. :)

Comment: You can check that answer for now as correct one and ask another question `jupyter` related. Glad to help. Good luck with it!